# How to effectively reuse mapped value

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

The program has the following input data:

```
std::map<std::string, std::vector<int> >
```

Now I need to convert this data structure into the following:

```
std::map<int, std::vector<int> >
```

Fo example:

```
"key1" => 1
"key2" => 20
etc.
```

Only the key type is changed, the mapped value is unchanged.

The question is that how I can reuse the mapped key `std::vector<int>` effectively so that the mappped value is not copied since there is no need to do so.

Here are two ideas that come to my mind:

////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Solution 1>

redefine the interface
from

```
std::map<int, std::vector<int> >
```

to

```
std::map<int, std::vector<int>* >
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Solution 2>
redefine the interface
from:

```
  std::map<std::string, std::vector<int> >
  std::map<int, std::vector<int> >
```

to:

```
  std::map<std::string, boost::shared_ptr<std::vector<int>> >
  std::map<int, boost::shared_ptr<std::vector<int>> >
```

In both cases, the cost of the copy is simply a copy of a pointer.

Any comment is appreciated

Comment: Will the original map `std::map<std::string, std::vector<int> >` become obsolete (can it be cleared) ?

Comment: The input is return-by-value. so it can be cleared. I assume that you suggest that we can use `std::move` which is only available for c++11, or `std::vector::swap`

Comment: VS2010 has a fair amount of support for C++11 features, actually, including `std::move` and r-value references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++11 provides move-operations to move one object to another without copying. VS 2010 should have the necessary machinery implemented. With this, assuming you have a mapping for old to new keys, you can remap the data like this:

```
std::map<std::string, std::vector> m1;
std::map<int, std::vector> m2;
std::map<std::string, int> keymap;

for (auto i=m1.begin(); i != m1.end(); ++i)
{
   m2[keymap[i->first]] = std::move(i->second);
}
```

Now, all vectors have been moved to a new map leaving the map m1 in an undefined, but destructible state.

If C++11 (as available in VS2010) is not an option, swap the new map with the old one:

```
std::map<std::string, std::vector> m1;
std::map<int, std::vector> m2;
std::map<std::string, int> keymap;

for (std::map<std::string, std::vector>::iterator i=m1.begin(); i != m1.end(); ++i)
{
   m2[keymap[i->first]].swap(i->second);
}
```